# How can I check for an empty association with a where statement in rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, where-clause

I have a model called Category that can have many subcategories (which are also Category records). I want to collect all Categories in the database that have no subcategories with something like:

```
Category.where(subcategories: [])
```

But every intuitive [to me] variation of this that I've tried either throws an error or returns an empty set. It's generating some SQL that I don't quite understand:

```
Category Load (0.5ms) SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE 1=0
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

Can anyone tell me the proper way to do this?

EDIT: This is the way the subcategories relationship is defined

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :subcategories, class_name: 'Category', foreign_key: 'parent_id'
    belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Category'
end
```

Comment: Could you try my solution using `joins` and `includes` individually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, solved. I just needed to tweak Sharvy's suggestion (one big thing I forgot is to add a "joins").

The following worked:

```
Category.includes(:subcategories).where(subcategories: nil)
```

**UPDATE 2:** OK, this time I *really* got it working (pretty sure, at least...). I had to use some ugly SQL rather than just some pretty ActiveRecord syntax, but the following seems to do what I want:

```
Category.joins("LEFT JOIN categories AS subcategories ON subcategories.parent_id = categories.id").where("subcategories IS NULL")
```

**UPDATE 1:** Sorry, nevermind, this doesn't work. As I commented below, I jumped the gun because I saw that this query was returning the proper category count for both `where(... nil)` and `where.not(... nil)`, but it wasn't actually returning the proper categories. It is returning all the categories that do not have a parent category rather than all the categories that do not have any subcategories.

Here is some sample output from this query:

```
Category.includes(:subcategories).where(subcategories: nil).last
  Category Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."parent_id" IS NULL  ORDER BY "categories"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  Category Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."parent_id" IN (3158)
 => #<Category id: 3158, name: "A parent", parent_id: nil, created_at: "2015-03-23 19:18:40", updated_at: "2015-03-23 19:18:40", operator_id: nil>
```

Comment: can you print the result of `Category.last` here?

Comment: Bah. I got thrown for a loop because it was returning the proper number of categories rather than returning the actual proper category records, but I guess you saw something I didn't, because it's not actually working. It is returning all the categories that don't have a parent rather than the categories that don't have any subcategories. I will edit that output into the answer.

Comment: Aren't those with no parent are actually categories ?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that it's possible for a category to have neither a parent, nor to have any subcategories. So I want to get all categories that only mean the latter condition to make sure I cover my bases.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not getting you, so what is the difference between category and sub-category since you are using the same model. How are you marking, that is which one is category and which one is sub category? Are you keeping any extra field or type something?

Comment: No, I'm not. The only difference is that a parent category will have subcategories, but a child level category will not. It's possible that a child-level category also does not have a parent assigned to it yet, also.

Comment: Yes that's true. But you can not add an attribute to identify a category with no subcategory. You have to find category by nil parent id. Otherwise you will have to keep a type attribute, or make another model for subcategories.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73622/discussion-between-pawan-agarawal-and-sharvy-ahmed).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Category.joins(:subcategories).where(subcategories: {parent_id: nil})
```

or

```
Category.includes(:subcategories).where('subcategories.parent_id IS NULL')
```

Comment: Both give me the error `PG::Error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "subcategories"`. I just edited into my post the way I have defined the subcategories relationship, if that helps.

Comment: Updated my answer, can you try now with `parent_id` in where clause ?

Comment: Still the same error for both. :/ One thing I tried just out of curiosity returned all the parent categories (categories for which subcategories was NOT empty) : `Category.joins(:subcategories).where(subcategories: nil)`. Am I onto anything there?

Comment: Eureka, I think I figured it out! Thanks for reminding me I needed the "joins". I'll post the answer in a second.

Answer (score 2):

Rails 6.1+ has added a method which makes this easier:

```
Category.where.missing(:subcategories)
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the accepted answer, I like this:

```
    Category.joins("LEFT JOIN categories as subcategories 
                    ON subcategories.parent_id = categories.id")
            .having("COUNT(subcategories.id) = 0")
```

It is a more generalized approach (obviously not as efficient) because *it would work with any number of tables that you need to join, not only two*.

---

Say for example, you have an `orders` table, which has many `line_items`, and a `subscriptions` table, which belongs to a `line_item`. To check which Orders contain NO Subscriptions:

```
  orders.joins('INNER JOIN line_items 
                ON line_items.order_id = orders.id 
                LEFT JOIN subscriptions
                ON subscriptions.line_item_id = line_items.id')
         .having("COUNT(subscriptions.id) = 0").group(:id)
```

Answer (score -1):

How about

```
Category.where("id NOT IN (?)", Subcategory.pluck(:category_id))
```

The issue here is that you can't directly query an association in a `.where` clause. You can only deal with the actual column names. So I did a quick subquery here where you grab the category IDs that are listed as associations in the Subcategory table, then query for all Categories not in that list.